# Access Denied - User doesn't have the access for the requested operation in UnionPay (WireCard)

Tags: payment-gateway, payment

I have using Wirecard Union Pay Payment but it return **Access Denied - User doesn't have the access for the requested operation!** error.

**Below is sandbox details;**

```
{
        "MerchantAccountId": "7139c728-cc91-11e3-ac9f-00163e1a318d",
        "PaymentMethod": "chinapay",
        "Mode": "sandbox",
        "UserName": "70000-APILUHN-CARD",
        "Password": "8mhwavKVb91T",
        "Url": "https://api-test.wirecard.com/engine/rest/paymentmethods"
}
```

**Header**
Basic NzAwMDAtQVBJTFVITi1DQVJEOjhtaHdhdktWYjkxVA==

**Request JSON**

```
{
   "payment":{
      "merchant-account-id":{
         "value":"7139c728-cc91-11e3-ac9f-00163e1a318d"
      },
      "request-id":"dd30edbf-240e-4b21-9bb5-d0d95319e6b1",
      "transaction-type":"authorization",
      "requested-amount":{
         "value":"1.01",
         "currency":"USD"
      },
      "account-holder":{
         "first-name":"Pawan",
         "last-name":"Shukla",
         "email":"pawan.shukla@wikaad.com",
         "phone":"+1(1)4161234567",
         "address":{
            "street1":"123 anystreet",
            "city":"Brantford",
            "country":"CA",
            "state":"ON"
         }
      },
      "order-number":"62598",
      "payment-methods":{
         "payment-method":[
            {
               "name":"chinapay"
            }
         ]
      },
      "cancel-redirect-url":"http://localhost:55152/Home/cancel",
      "success-redirect-url":"http://localhost:55152/Home/success",
      "fail-redirect-url":"http://localhost:55152/Home/fail",
      "ip-address":"127.0.0.1"
   }
}
```

If i send request to wirecard then in will return below response.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<payment xmlns="http://www.elastic-payments.com/schema/payment" xmlns:ns2="http://www.elastic-payments.com/schema/epa/transaction">
    <transaction-state>failed</transaction-state>
    <statuses>
        <status code="403.1166" description="Access Denied - User doesn't have the access for the requested operation!" severity="error"/>
    </statuses>
```

So Please let me what i am missing.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: We solved our problem. Our credentials where wrong. How do you send the request? We are using basic auth and it's working without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with other test account?

WIRECARD_USERNAME = "70000-APIDEMO-CARD"

WIRECARD_PASSWORD = "ohysS0-dvfMx"

or

WIRECARD_USERNAME =  "70000-APILUHN-CARD"

WIRECARD_PASSWORD =  "8mhwavKVb91T"